# Returning original string with symbols between each character

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my program return the exact same string but with `**` between each character. Here's my code.

```
def separate(st):
    total = " "
    n = len(st + st[-1])

    for i in range(n):
        total = str(total) + str(i) + str("**")
    return total

x = separate("12abc3")
print(x)
```

This should return:

```
1**2**a**b**c**3**
```

However, I'm getting `0**1**2**3**4**5**6**`.

Comment: You should be using your parameter `st` not the built in function `str`.

Comment: You're just concatenating `i`. Not any character from `st`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the characters in the string together with `"**"` as the separator (this works because strings are basically lists in Python). To get the additional `"**"` at the end, just concatenate.

Here's an example:

```
def separate(st):
    return "**".join(st) + "**"
```

Sample:

```
x = separate("12abc3")
print(x) # "1**2**a**b**c**3**"
```

A note on your posted code:

The reason you get the output you do is because you loop using `for i in range(n):` so the iteration variable `i` will be each index in `st`. Then when you call `str(total) + str(i) + str("**")`, you cast `i` to a string, and `i` was just each index (from `0` to `n-1`) in `st`.

To fix that you could iterate over the characters in `st` directly, like this:

```
for c in st:
```

or use the index `i` to get the character at each position in `st`, like this:

```
for i in range(len(st)):
    total = total + st[i] + "**"
```

Comment: Don't even need to split into list? Tested on Python 3.6.6 Windows

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped out!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow!

I will explain part of your code line by line.

`for i in range(n)` since you are only providing 1 parameter (which is for the stopping point), this will loop starting from n = 0, 1, 2, ... , n-1

`total = str(total) + str(i) + str("**")` this add `i` (which is the current number of iteration - 1) and `**` to the current `total` string. Hence, which it is adding those numbers sequentially to the result.

What you should do instead is `total = str(total) + st[i] + str("**")` so that it will add each character of `st` one by one

In addition, you could initialize `n` as `n = len(st)`